# Prestashop 1.6: extra product_attribute field and display it at the product page depending on the choice of the attribute

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

I have a little question

I have already added an extra field to my product table and this is working very well.

What I want:
But now I want to add an extra field to the `ps_product_attribute` table and display it below the price depending on the attribute that is selected by the customer.

A little more info: 
When you use the `Prestashop` combinations you can add a reference to every combination. When the customer changes the combination, the reference name is automatically changed (refreshed?) on the product page. So the displayed reference name is depending on the choice of combination the customer is making. This is working fine.

Now just like this I want to display my extra field from my `ps_product_attribute` table below the price. The extra field is containing a specific price unit that is depending on the attribute choice.

My problem:
I have already added the extra field to the database table (`ps_product_attribute`) but I do not know how I can display this on on the product page

and

how the value is refreshed (or changed) when the customer selects another combination.

I hope you understand my question. Any help would be grateful.